# Add-Content - append to specific line

Tags: powershell

I want to add text into specific line of txt file. I can't find any solution on internet.

This code adds text in further line (I want for example second line):

```
$test_out = "test"

$test_out | Add-Content "C:\tmp\test.txt"
```

Comment: do you want to replace the line? Modify it? Prepend or append the text?

Comment: Modify it - add text into the specific line.

Comment: At the beginning? The end? Somewhere in the middle (where)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to add text to the end of a specific line, you can do it like this

```
$fileContent = Get-Content $filePath
$fileContent[$lineNumber-1] += $textToAdd
$fileContent | Set-Content $filePath
```

If you want to replace the text instead of adding, just remove the '+' sign.
You do of course have to set the variables
$filePath, $textToAdd and $lineNumber first.

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution which reads the content of the file and access the line using the array index (-1). This example adds the line `test` and a line break to the second line.

```
$filePath = 'C:\tmp\test.txt'
$test_out = "test"

$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath
$fileContent[1] = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $test_out, $fileContent[1]

$fileContent | Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Cannot index into a null array.
At line:5 char:1
+ $fileContent[1] = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $test_out, $fileContent[1]

Comment: then your test.txt doesnt contain 2 lines?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but the above does work and was exactly what I was looking for. For my case i needed to add a line under another line. If that's you're case use "{1}`r`n{0}"

Comment: `"{0}\`r\`n{1}" -f` is called the format operator, and it replaces {0} and {1} in the string with the subsequent values `$test_out` and `$fileContent[1]`. It's a lot like how `printf` works in other languages.

Comment: Thank you @Prid for the explanation! Looks like I was to lazy... Cheers ✌