# Append to end of specific line in Powershell or Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to figure out how to append a string to the end of a specific line in a file.

Example file:

```
Some text
...
LineToAppendTo,otherrandomtext,...,endoflinetext
...
End of file text
```

I do not know the line number of the "LineToAppendTo" line. All i know is that the line begins with the text "LineToAppendTo" and then a bunch of random text that I do not know or care about. All I want to do is append a string ",appendedString" to the end of that line.

Using the example i gave above the output would be:

```
Some text
...
LineToAppendTo,otherrandomtext,...,endoflinetext,appendedString
...
End of file text
```

How would I do this is powershell (if not powershell I can use batch also)?

Comment: Have tou tried anything on your own? please ahare your code!

Answer (score 4):

```
(gc D:\in.txt) -replace '^LineToAppendTo.*', '$0,AppendText' | sc d:\out.txt
```

Get the lines, replace lines beggining with "LineToAppendTo" with themselves followed by ",AppendText" (the others stay the same). Output the lines to a file.

If you don't want to use regexes, you could easily:

```
gc D:\in.txt |% {
    if ($_.StartsWith('LineToAppendTo')) {"$_,AppendText"} else {$_} 
} | sc d:\out.txt
```

--

- Both are using `gc` for `Get-Content` and `sc` for `Set-Content`.
- The first uses the fact that `-replace` acts on every item in an array.
- The second uses `%` as `ForEach-Object` to explicitly loop over each line.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function, I've tested it out and its working. The function `AppendToFile` takes in 2 parameters `PathToFile` and `TextToAdd`. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
Function AppendToFile {

    param([String]$PathToFile, [String]$TextToAdd)

    $lines = Get-Content $PathToFile | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 

    foreach ($line in $lines) {
        if ($line -like "LineToAppendTo*") {
            $lines[$lines.IndexOf($line)] += $TextToAdd
        }
    }
    $lines | Set-Content $PathToFile
}

# example use of function
AppendToFile -PathToFile "C:\myTextFile.txt" -TextToAdd "add this"
```

Modified from the solution here: [Add-Content - append to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957901/add-content-to-specific-line)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~1"
set "PREFIX=LineToAppendTo"
set "SUFFIX=,appendedString"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%FILE%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%S in ("!LINE:*:=!") do (
        endlocal
        set "STRING=%%S"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!STRING!"=="!PREFIX!" (
            echo(!LINE!!SUFFIX!
        ) else (
            echo(!LINE!
        )
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The text file, given as command line argument, is read by a `for /F` loop line by line. Each line is split at the first `,`, the portion in front of it is compared with the prefix `LineToAppendTo`. If equal, the line is output with the suffix `,appendedString` appended; if not, the line is output unedited.

If you want to store the output into a file, use redirection, supposing the script is called `append.bat`:

```
append.bat "\path\to\input_file.txt" > "\path\to\output_file.txt"
```