# How to put and remove comment on line 20 using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to use Powershell to put comment character at the beginning of line 20 of configuration file, run script and then remove the comment character from line 20.

I considered to use .replace functionality, but it doesn't help me, because line 20 in my configuration is not unique:

```
(Get-Content d:\docker-compose.yml).replace('- .:/myapp', '# .:/myapp') | Set-Content d:\docker-compose.yml
# ... command to run script ...
(Get-Content d:\docker-compose.yml).replace('# .:/myapp', '- .:/myapp') | Set-Content d:\docker-compose.yml
```

**Answer**

Thanks for the suggestions. With the link you gave me I ended up with following solution:

```
$lineNumber = 20
$filePath = "d:\docker-compose.yml"

$fileContent = Get-Content $filePath
$fileContent[$lineNumber-1] = $fileContent[$lineNumber-1].replace('- .:/myapp', '# .:/myapp')
$fileContent | Set-Content $filePath

# ... command to run script ...

$fileContent = Get-Content $filePath
$fileContent[$lineNumber-1] = $fileContent[$lineNumber-1].replace('# .:/myapp', '- .:/myapp')
$fileContent | Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: By saying that "is not unique" you mean that you get more lines commented than only your line 20, correct?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for this: [Add-Content - append to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957901/add-content-append-to-specific-line)

Comment: @DaemonPainter : Yes and thank you.