# Add Content to a specific line in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have seen this post:
[Add-Content - append to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957901/add-content-append-to-specific-line)

But I cannot add these lines because "Array index is out of range".

What my script is doing:

1. Find the line
2. Loop through the array that contains the data i want to add
3. $file[$line]+=$data
4. $line+=1
5. Write to file

Should I create a new file content and then add each line of the original file to it?
IF so, do you know how to do that and how to stop and add my data in between?

Here is the part of my code where I try to add:

```
$f=Get-Content $path
$ct=$begin+1 #$begin is the line where I want to place content under
foreach($add in $add_to_yaml)
{
     $f[$ct]+=$add
     $ct+=1
}
$f | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

Comment: Please just post the code instead of describing the code

Comment: Remove `$ct+=1` - you keep concatenating to the _string_ that's stored in `$f[$ct]`, so the number of strings in the `$f` array itself remains unchanged, meaning you don't need to "advance" the position at which you're writing. You might want to replace `$f[$ct]+=$add` with `$f[$ct] = $f[$ct],$add -join [Environment]::NewLine` to get line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your script and try to analyze what's going on:

```
$f = Get-Content $path
```

`Get-Content`, by default, reads text files and spits out 1 string per individual line in the file. If the file found at `$path` has 10 lines, the resulting value stored in `$f` will be an array of 10 string values.

Worth noting is that array indices in PowerShell (and .NET in general) are *zero-based* - to get the 10th line from the file, we'd reference index 9 in the array (`$f[9]`).

That means that if you want to concatenate stuff to the end of (or "under") line 10, you need to specify index 9. For this reason, you'll want to change the following line:

```
$ct = $begin + 1 #$begin is the line where i want to place content under
```

to

```
$ct = $begin
```

Now that we have the correct starting offset, let's look at the loop:

```
foreach($add in $add_to_yaml)
{
     $f[$ct] += $add
     $ct += 1
}
```

Assuming `$add_to_yaml` contains multiple strings, the loop body will execute *more than once*. Let's take a look at the first statement:

```
$f[$ct] += $add
```

We know that `$f[$ct]` resolves to a *string* - and strings have the `+=` operator overloaded to mean "string concatenation". That means that the string value stored in `$f[$ct]` will be modified (eg. the string will become longer), but the array `$f` itself does *not* change its size - it still contains the same number of strings, just one of them is a little longer.

Which brings us to the crux of your issue, this line right here:

```
$ct += 1
```

By incrementing the index counter, you effectively "skip" to the next string for every value in `$add_to_yaml` - so if the number of elements you want to add exceeds the number of lines after `$begin`, you naturally reach a point "beyond the bounds" of the array before you're finished.

Instead of incrementing `$ct`, make sure you concatenate your new string values with a newline sequence:

```
$f[$ct] = $f[$ct],$add -join [Environment]::Newline
```

Putting it all back together, you end up with something like this (notice we can discard `$ct` completely, since its value is constant an equal to `$begin` anyway):

```
$f = Get-Content $path

foreach($add in $add_to_yaml)
{
    $f[$begin] = $f[$begin],$add -join [Environment]::Newline
}
```

But wait a minute - all the strings in `$add_to_yaml` are simply going to be joined by newlines - we can do that in a single `-join` operation and get rid of the loop too!

```
$f = Get-Content $path
$f[$begin] = @($f[$begin];$add_to_yaml) -join [Environment]::Newline
$f | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

Much simpler :)

Comment: And now i can even understand why your script is working. Thank you so much for the explanation! I am sure it will also help others.